# selected menu item in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating my first mvc3 application (no previous mvc either) I am wanting to create a top level menu and be able to add a "selected" or "active" css class to the select LI tag. I found this link [active menu item - asp.net mvc3 master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728777/active-menu-item-asp-net-mvc3-master-page) Ihave tried to add it to a class however I get an error back "Error   1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\MvcMusicStore-v2.0\MvcMusicStore-Completed\MvcMusicStore\Helpers\HtmlHelpers.cs  26  31  MvcMusicStore
"

So I am thinking I am missing a reference to something however I don't know what. Can someone kindly tell me what I need to reference to get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following using at the top of your `HtmlHelpers.cs` file:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

Now the `htmlHelper.ActionLink` line should compile just fine.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I see you were the orginal person that suggested the code to Michael. I have created a helper class and added your example however I get this error Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'MenuLink' and no extension method 'MenuLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) g:\MvcMusicStore-v2.0\MvcMusicStore-Completed\MvcMusicStore\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml MvcMusicStore
Do I need to add a reference in my view to the helper class?

Comment: @user293545, yes you need to reference the namespace that this helper has been declared into. You could do this directly in the View by adding an `@using` clause or better yet add it to the `~/Views/Web.config` inside the `<namespaces>` tag of the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` tag which will allow you to use the helper method in all razor views without having to explicitly declare it.