# how to highlight selected tab of master page in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i have created a master page with lots of effort but i am not able to figure out how to make my tab selected based on the user click.
i have used one method to do that but finding very complicated as i have pass a viewdata from each of my controller which i dont like it, below is how i have done code in controller

```
ViewData["ActiveMenu"] = "Inbox";
```

and in my master page i have written a jquery like below to make the tab highlighted.

```
$('#lnkInbox').mouseout(function () {
            $('#aInbox').removeClass('aInbox-Hover');
            $('#aInbox').addClass('aInbox');

            //put hover effect on the selected menu
            var activeMenu = '<%:ViewData["ActiveMenu"] %>';
            if (activeMenu == "Account") {
                $('#aAccount').removeClass('aAccount');
                $('#aAccount').addClass('aAccount-Hover');

            }});
```

this is how i am doing but is there any other way i can do that...

please suggest
i have found one good link [active menu item - asp.net mvc3 master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728777/active-menu-item-asp-net-mvc3-master-page)
but the answer which is showed there i am not able understand how to i utilize in my code and where to write the code in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [answer you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728777/active-menu-item-asp-net-mvc3-master-page).
To create helper class add new class to you project, i.e. like this

```
public static class LinkHelpers
{
//copy here the first block of code from the answer
}
```

Add to your HomeController methods (probably you already have them):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult About()
   {
     return View()
   }
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
     return View()
   }
}
```

Create respective views and add to your master page

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.MenuLink("Main", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.MenuLink("About us", "About", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

And finally in your css file declare

```
.current{background-color:red;}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment but where should i add the static class (in my controller create a static class or in the action of the controller)

Comment: @aamankhaan No, create a separate file, i.e. in the root of your project